# Ruby flavoured Regex: A[[:digit:]]* accepts character at the beginning of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following Ruby flavoured regex:

```
data.to_s.match(/\A[[:digit:]]*+((.|,)[[:digit:]]+)?\Z/) ? true : false
```

This returns true for the following examples as intended:

```
data = "13"
data = "1,3"
data = "13,3"
data = "1.3"
data = ",3"
data = ".3"
```

What is not clear to me is why the asterix after the first [[:digit:]] also allows a character to be passed at the beginning of the string:

```
irb > "a3".match(/\A[[:digit:]]*+((.|,)[[:digit:]]+)?\Z/)
=> #<MatchData "a3" 1:"a3" 2:"a">
```

How can I have it only match digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` is a regexp metachar that matches any character (except newline) you need to escape it in your alternation:

```
data.to_s.match(/\A[[:digit:]]*((\.|,)[[:digit:]]+)?\Z/) ? true : false
# this dot needs escaping         ^
```

Also the `+` after the first `*` is redundant (one or more repetitions of zero or more digits). Also ruby has a shorter friendly way to say `[[:digit:]]`: `\d`. Since this is a whole string match, do you really want to allow `\n` at end of string?  If not, use `\z` over `\Z`

```
data.to_s.match(/\A\d*((\.|,)\d+)?\z/) ? true : false
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.` in your regex is matching any character and needs to be escaped as `\.`:

```
data.to_s.match(/\A[[:digit:]]*+((\.|,)[[:digit:]]+)?\Z/) ? true : false
```